# How to join the broken wooden piece (from a bedside table)?

Tags: joinery, wood-repair

I have this piece from a small bed-side table. It is 44 cms long. The point it is broken has the smallest dimensions 17 x 19 mms. I want to fix (join) it myself. The best experience working with wooden furniture I have is assembling Ikea furniture (desk, cot, book shelf, chairs, etc.).

Is it possible? Please suggest what is the best approach?

Here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Actual table has dimensions of 44L x 33w x 29.5ht (in cms):

[image]

The unassembled table as seen from bottom (the circled points have screw  holes to fasten) with the drawer removed:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  It would be helpful if you could include a photo showing the full table and how this piece fits into the assembly.  While the two pieces can easily be glued together, it is unclear how much stress the repair joint will be under so that additional reinforcement might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post. I will post a picture of the table little later (I have to find the picture from where I had purchased 5+ years back).

Comment: A picture from today showing the whole table, with the spot where the missing piece front and center in the pic, will be more than sufficient. We don't really need a "pristine" picture. Actually, showing us where the piece came from is really what we need to see.

Comment: @FreeMan I have included the picture.

Comment: I assume the broken piece is the front face of the base of the table.  You can glue the pieces together and reinforce it on the back (hidden) face with a metal plate extending 4" +/- on each side of the crack using several screws on each side.

Comment: Yes, the broken piece is the front base part of the table (the back part as you see in the last picture is intact and has slightly different shape ). I will try this out sometime. Thanks for the guidance.